# Simultaneous quotation mark editing in JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, phpstorm

In PhpStorm (and other JetBrains IDEs), there is a nice option when typing HTML to edit both HTML tags as you type, so that they are always in sync:

```
return '<buttond class="btn"> hello </buttond>'
```

It is managed by the setting: **Simultaneous <tag></tag> editing** in PhpStorm.

I was wondering if there was something similar for quotation marks, and even symbols like `()`, `{}` and `[]` so that the closest quotation mark would also be modified, to avoid stuff like this:

```
return "<button class="btn"> hello </button>'
```

I understand that this would cause syntax errors, since if you change the symbol you change the inner content's structure, but if the IDE can tell when a quotation ends, is it possible to do this as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that this would cause syntax errors,

Why? **If it's PHP** then just use the appropriate quick fix action from the Intentions/Quick Fix menu (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> here on Windows or by using a mouse on the light bulb icon):

[image]

Final result:

```php
return "<buttond class=\"btn\"> hello </buttond>";
```

> I was wondering if there was something similar for quotation marks, and even symbols like `()`, `{}` and `[]` so that the closest quotation mark would also be modified...

Check options under `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Smart Keys`

[image]

This will work for quotes changing.

For brackets/braces etc it's more about inserting the closing one automatically when typing the opening one. Although in some contexts it will also work: **e.g. in JSON file**, change the opening `{` by `[` and it will also replace the closing `}` to `]`.